# How to create distributable static libraries with which do not produce conflicts and export only selected symbols on Clang/CMake/iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, cmake, clang, static-libraries

I have a C++ project with many libraries that is built with Clang using CMake. The purpose of this project is to compile library `X` which I distribute to clients along with its API headers. The API itself is completely 'isolated' and depends only on C++ standard headers.

When building a static library for iOS I compile all the libraries (`make install`) and then combine them into single static library using `libtool -static`. When distributing it to clients I've faced a problem.

Suppose the libraries on which public library `X` depends on internally are named `A` and `B`. 
Also, suppose library `A` is a popular library used by many people and the client happens to be linking library `A` of different version to his executable along with library `X` (which already has `A` object files inside).

This results either in duplicate symbols or even worse - our library `X` somehow starts calling functions from client's `A` of different version sometimes resulting in crash (that happened with libpng library).

**Question.**
What is a proper way to create such an isolated static library that would expose (via `nm` command and especially during the linking stage to the final executable) only the symbols that are present in the `X` public API?

Would be great if it would be a compiler command that I could add to CMake configuration. Also, I really don't want to modify the source code (e.g. add namespaces and so on) as it's complicated for third party libraries.

I've been looking into symbol visibility, relocatable pre-linking, striping and other techniques but I'm not sure I'm on the right track as this problem must have happened before to many people and it's strange I failed to find a solution after many days of searching and experimenting.

Comment: this is what namespaces are for

Comment: @RichardHodges thanks, I've updated the question. I want to avoid namespaces as the solution must be project-wide. The public API `X` is of course namespaced.

Comment: google the `visibility` option for gcc/clang. There is a similar thing for microsoft. It allows you to mark some symbols as visible outside the library and some not.

Comment: @RichardHodges how can visibility be specified for static libraries? I can't get it to work. If I set `fvisibility=hidden` for the whole project then nothing changes.

Comment: Some ancient words of wisdom from the apple dev team here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/CppRuntimeEnv/Articles/SymbolVisibility.html

Comment: @RichardHodges I've been reading this article for a while now, I'm confused by the part in the beginning where they say "In a shared library containing many files, though,...". Do you have an experience of actually controlling symbol visibility for static libraries?

Comment: I have seen the results of it when compiling boost statically for use with iOS applications (you get a load of linker warnings about symbol visibility when using boost.log get). However, I have always chosen the route of using internal namespaces for my own separation in static libraries.

Comment: So far it seems that visibility specification doesn't work for static libraries.

Comment: I guess namespaces is the way to go then?